# Incremental parquet files

Tags: amazon-web-services, pyspark, amazon-redshift, parquet

I've got data from an on-prem that is being loaded into an s3 bucket. The data will be transformed using EMR/PySpark and with a surrogate key added during this process. The parquet files will then get loaded into RedShift.

I want incremntally update the RedShift data warehouse when there are data changes or new records that come in.

I want to get some opinions on my approach. Let's say I'm loading a list of accounts

1. CSV file dropped into S3 bucket
2. EMR/PySpark script transcript runs and generates surrogate keys (these will be just sequential numbers for each account. The parquet file is then loaded into Redsfhit
3. Now, a new csv is dropped into s3. The pyspark script will join against the full parquet tranformed file to check if the account exists. If it exists, it will take the surrogate key. If it doesn't, then a surrogate key will be generated.
4. The new csv of accounts are then merged in with the full parquet file
5. The new csv of accounts will also be saved in a new parquet file which is then used to load into Redshift.

However, I'm not sure if this solution is ideal because Steps 3/4 require loading the full parquet file.

The reason I'm also wanting to use this approach is so that if say later down the track, we decide to switch data warehouses, we can simply use those same parquet files into the data warehouse.

Comment: Rather than "loading" the data in S3, you could create an external "Redshift Spectrum" table that reads the data directly from S3 without loading it into Redshift. While it isn't as efficient for queries as data stored directly in Redshift, it makes it easy to load data from S3. You can even JOIN with the external table to do your matching.

Comment: Thanks. I'll look into that. But I guess my question relating to the surrogate key. I'm not sure it's the best approach to use?

Comment: Or maybe the full parquet file should just contain a mapping key with the primary key from the source system along with its surrogate key.

Comment: How much is your total data volume? My guess is you could just reprocess all the files all at once and pick the latest version of each row based on the s3 filename it’s in (with spectrum that’s the “$path” variable. That way you can just use your raw data and not worry about preprocessing it or injecting any surrogate keys.